# How to insert a model in mysql with spark and java

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to apache spark and i want to insert model class in to mysql Db using spark in java.

I have tried using below code. but its not working properly.

**model:**

```
public class User implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String city;
private String country;
private String ip;

private static StructType structType = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
        DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
        DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("email", DataTypes.StringType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("city", DataTypes.StringType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("country", DataTypes.StringType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("ip", DataTypes.StringType, true)
});

//getters & setters
```

**MyApp:**

```
public class MyApp {

private static final String MYSQL_USERNAME = "root";
private static final String MYSQL_PWD = "";
private static final String MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample?user=" + MYSQL_USERNAME + "&password=" + MYSQL_PWD;

private static final JavaSparkContext sc =
        new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkSaveToDb").setMaster("local[*]"));

private static final SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Sample data-frame loaded from a JSON file
    try{

        List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

        User us = new User();
        us.setId(1);
        us.setName("Ravi");
        us.setEmail("abc.xyz0@gmail.com");
        us.setCity("hyderabad");
        us.setCountry("India");
        us.setIp("127.0.0.1");
        list.add(us);

        //Creating RDD
        JavaRDD<User> personsRDD = sc.parallelize(list);
        DataFrame userDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(personsRDD, User.class);

        //JdbcUtils.saveTable(userDf, MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, "users", prop);
        userDf.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, "users", new java.util.Properties());

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

When i run the above code i am getting the below exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'hyderabad' for column 'id' at row 1**
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
```

Could anyone please let me know how to resolve this issue and insert in to  mysql DB. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**First**

If your Table implement an `AUTO_INCREMENT` if your `id` like this :

```
id int AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Then you don't need to set the id `us.setId(1);`, this can make a problem, consider you already have a use this this `id = 1` so when you put `us.setId(1);` this is a conflict, so don't use `us.setId(1);`

Else you should to check first if this id not exist.

**Second**

> Incorrect integer value: 'hyderabad' for column 'id' at row 1

This error mean that you set a `'hyderabad'` String to your id of type integer so you are making some thing like this :

If this your table :

```
create table mytable(
id int,
....
);
```

Then your query seams like this :

```
Insert into mytable (id, ...) values ('hyderabad', ...);
```

And this not correct, so check your insert query maybe you just changed the order of your attributes.

Comment: Thanks  for the reply. yes the 'id' is 'AUTO_INCREMENT', but even if i comment the 'us.sedId(1)' i get the  error **'java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'Hyderabad' for column 'id' at row 1 '** and the table is a newly created table.